# Android: Display SQLite record in a TextView

Tags: android, sqlite

I asked a question before but I feel I phrased it wrong. I wish to select the top 3 scores from the "Score" table and populate 3 textViews in the high score activity.

Database Adapter Class;

```
//Primary Key for the score
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
//Field for user score
public static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";

//Database name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SportsQuizDB";
//Database table name
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Score";
//Database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private dbHelper dbHelper;
private final Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

private static class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    //Constructor for dbHelper
    public dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_SCORE + " INTEGER NOT NULL);"
        );
    }

    //This method is over ridden from its super class.  If the     
    //database it out of date then it is updated in the constructor     
    //and logged here.  Once updated the tables are dropped and     
    //onCreate is recalled.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }


} 

public Adapter(Context c)
{
    context = c;
}

public Adapter open()
{
    try{
    dbHelper = new dbHelper(context);
    sqlDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Log.e("Open(); ",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    return this;
}

public Cursor selectTop3()
{
    //I began to attempt the select form the SQLite DB
    //But I am unsure how to use the cursor to populate the TextViews
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" ORDER BY " + KEY_SCORE + " DESC ";
    Cursor c = sqlDB.rawQuery(query, null);
    return c;
}

public void close()
{
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

The HighScore Class containing the 3 TextViews.

```
public class HighScores extends Activity {
TextView result1, result2, result3;

Adapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Removes Title Bar 
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Removes Notification Bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_scores);

    result1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result1);
    result2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);
    result3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result3);

    fillHighScores();


}

private void fillHighScores() {
    openDB();
    //This it where I wish to populate the three TextViews (result1, result2, result3)

    closeDB();  
}

private void openDB() {
    adapter = new Adapter(this);
    adapter.open();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    closeDB();
}

private void closeDB() {
    adapter.close();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
```

I have been trying for 2 days now on what seems to be a simple process. It appear to me that android SQLite is over confusing and long winded. If anyone can shine some light that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the adapter but what you need is an instance of your SQLiteOpenHelper and call the function getReadableDatabase. With the database do your query for the top 3 results.

Here is a great tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Parsing the cursor can be a pain. There are a couple of libraries you might want to check out. Green DAO and ORM Lite.